# NLTK accuracy: "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, nltk, text-classification

I'm trying to do some sentiment analysis of a new movie from Twitter using the NLTK toolkit. I've followed the NLTK 'movie_reviews' example and I've built my own CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader object. The problem arises when I call `nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)`. Here is the code:

```
import os
import glob
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

def word_feats(words):
        return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

trainfeats = negfeats + posfeats

# Building a custom Corpus Reader
tweets = nltk.corpus.reader.CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('./tweets', r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(.*)\.txt')
tweetsids = tweets.fileids()
testfeats = [(word_feats(tweets.words(fileids=[f]))) for f in tweetsids]

print 'Training the classifier'
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)

for tweet in tweetsids:
        print tweet + ' : ' + classifier.classify(word_feats(tweets.words(tweetsids)))

classifier.show_most_informative_features()

print 'accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)
```

It all seems to work fine until it gets to the last line. That's when I get the error:

```
>>> nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/util.py", line 87, in accuracy
    results = classifier.classify_many([fs for (fs,l) in gold])
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Does anybody see anything wrong within the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/util.py", line 87, in accuracy
  results = classifier.classify_many([fs for (fs,l) in gold])
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

arises because items in `gold` can not be unpacked into a 2-tuple, `(fs,l)`:

```
[fs for (fs,l) in gold]  # <-- The ValueError is raised here
```

It is the same error you would get if `gold` equals `[(1,2,3)]`, since the 3-tuple `(1,2,3)` can not be unpacked into a 2-tuple `(fs,l)`:

```
In [74]: [fs for (fs,l) in [(1,2)]]
Out[74]: [1]
In [73]: [fs for (fs,l) in [(1,2,3)]]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

`gold` might be buried inside the implementation of `nltk.classify.util.accuracy`, but this hints that your inputs, `classifier` or `testfeats` are of the wrong "shape".

There is no problem with classifer, since calling `accuracy(classifier, trainfeats)` 
works:

```
In [61]: print 'accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, trainfeats)
accuracy: 0.9675
```

The problem must be in `testfeats`.

---

Compare `trainfeats` with `testfeats`. 
`trainfeats[0]` is a 2-tuple containing a dict and a classification:

```
In [63]: trainfeats[0]
Out[63]: 
({u'!': True,
  u'"': True,
  u'&': True,
  ...
  u'years': True,
  u'you': True,
  u'your': True},
 'neg')           # <---  Notice the classification, 'neg'
```

but `testfeats[0]` is just a dict, `word_feats(tweets.words(fileids=[f]))`:

```
testfeats = [(word_feats(tweets.words(fileids=[f]))) for f in tweetsids]
```

So to fix this you would need to define `testfeats` to look more like `trainfeats` -- each dict returned by `word_feats` must be paired with a classification.

Comment: You're right. As you said, the problem was that testfeats wasn't a tuple of [dictionary, classification_string]. Thank you